# Bootstrap columns and Wordpress Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

So I'm converting bootstrap site to Wordpress and post cards don't want to stack horizontally... I know there should be foreach loop which will loop through posts but I don't know how to set it up...

```
       <?php while(have_posts()) {
        the_post();

 ?>


    <section id="blog" class="py-3">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4">
                   <div class="card-columns">
                       <div class="card">
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium')?>" alt="" class="img-fluid card-img-top">
                           <div class="card-body">
                               <h4 class="card-title">
                                   <?php the_title(); ?>
                               </h4>
                               <small class="text-muted">Written by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></small>
                               <hr>
                               <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                           </div>
                       </div>                 
                     </div> 
                   </div>
               </div>
   </section>

   <?php     } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while` is also a loop. Inside the loop, you can just put the repeated code. As I've understood your code than you need to something like this:

```
<section id="blog" class="py-3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php while( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card-columns">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium')?>" alt="" class="img-fluid card-img-top">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">
                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </h4>
                                <small class="text-muted">Written by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></small>
                                <hr>
                                <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Also, better to move code for one block to another file for example `partials/post.php`:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium')?>" alt="" class="img-fluid card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h4>
                <small class="text-muted">Written by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></small>
                <hr>
                <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And update your current file:

```
<section id="blog" class="py-3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php while( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();
                get_template_part( 'partials/post' );
            } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much... I was doing the same thing, putting while loop after row, seems like card-column div was the problem for cards not stacking horizontally... Anyways, solved it, thanks :)

Comment: @COBNETCKNN Then you can mark this answer as correct click on the checkmark under answer vote.